# Use WebClient with socks proxy

Tags: c#, .net, socks, webclient

Is there any way to use a socks proxy with `WebClient`? Specifically with the `DownloadString` method that it provides?

I don't want to use any third party stuff like privoxy, freecap whatever and I can't use commercial libraries like those from Chilkat. I tried using stuff from http://www.mentalis.org/ in fact I used their `WebRequest` implementation but they don't seem to have something similar for WebClient.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) is not supported directly by the [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)/[`WebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) classes and by extension, the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class (it relies on `WebRequest` to do its work).

It really can't, as it works on the transport layer (TCP/IP) and not through a simple redirect to a server that forwards HTTP requests (which is the level that the `WebRequest`/`WebResponse` classes work on).

You can create a [specialized derivation of `WebRequest`/`WebResponse`](http://ditrans.blogspot.com/2009/03/making-witty-work-with-socks-proxy.html) (that uses [`ProxySocket`](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=9) to handle the low-level handshaking and then) and then create a specialized [`WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) which overrides the [`GetWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.getwebrequest.aspx) and [`GetWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.getwebresponse.aspx) methods.

Once you have that class substituted for your `WebClient` instances, it should work as normal (you might have to set up the proxy in each case where you use it though).

Answer (score 14):

Here is how I ended up doing it, thank you casperOne for the answer

```
public class SocksWebClient : WebClient
    {
        public IProxyDetails ProxyDetails { get; set; }
        public string UserAgent { get; set; }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest result = null;

            if (ProxyDetails != null)
            {
                if (ProxyDetails.ProxyType == ProxyType.Proxy)
                {
                    result = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
                    result.Proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyDetails.FullProxyAddress);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserAgent))
                        ((HttpWebRequest)result).UserAgent = UserAgent;
                }
                else if (ProxyDetails.ProxyType == ProxyType.Socks)
                {
                    result = SocksHttpWebRequest.Create(address);
                    result.Proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyDetails.FullProxyAddress);
                    //TODO: implement user and password

                }
                else if (ProxyDetails.ProxyType == ProxyType.None)
                {
                    result = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserAgent))
                        ((HttpWebRequest)result).UserAgent = UserAgent;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserAgent))
                    ((HttpWebRequest)result).UserAgent = UserAgent;
            }


            return result;
        }

    }
```

The `SocksHttpWebRequest` class is taken from the [blog](http://ditrans.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/making-witty-work-with-socks-proxy.html) linked to by @casperOne, the code for which is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using Org.Mentalis.Network.ProxySocket;

namespace Ditrans
{
    public class SocksHttpWebRequest : WebRequest
    {

        #region Member Variables

        private readonly Uri _requestUri;
        private WebHeaderCollection _requestHeaders;
        private string _method;
        private SocksHttpWebResponse _response;
        private string _requestMessage;
        private byte[] _requestContentBuffer;

        // darn MS for making everything internal (yeah, I'm talking about you, System.net.KnownHttpVerb)
        static readonly StringCollection validHttpVerbs =
            new StringCollection { "GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "TRACE", "OPTIONS" };

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        private SocksHttpWebRequest(Uri requestUri)
        {
            _requestUri = requestUri;
        }

        #endregion

        #region WebRequest Members

        public override WebResponse GetResponse()
        {
            if (Proxy == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Proxy property cannot be null.");
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Method))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Method has not been set.");
            }

            if (RequestSubmitted)
            {
                return _response;
            }
            _response = InternalGetResponse();
            RequestSubmitted = true;
            return _response;
        }

        public override Uri RequestUri
        {
            get { return _requestUri; }
        }

        public override IWebProxy Proxy { get; set; }

        public override WebHeaderCollection Headers
        {
            get
            {
                if (_requestHeaders == null)
                {
                    _requestHeaders = new WebHeaderCollection();
                }
                return _requestHeaders;
            }
            set
            {
                if (RequestSubmitted)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted.");
                }
                _requestHeaders = value;
            }
        }

        public bool RequestSubmitted { get; private set; }

        public override string Method
        {
            get
            {
                return _method ?? "GET";
            }
            set
            {
                if (validHttpVerbs.Contains(value))
                {
                    _method = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", string.Format("'{0}' is not a known HTTP verb.", value));
                }
            }
        }

        public override long ContentLength { get; set; }

        public override string ContentType { get; set; }

        public override Stream GetRequestStream()
        {
            if (RequestSubmitted)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted.");
            }

            if (_requestContentBuffer == null)
            {
                _requestContentBuffer = new byte[ContentLength];
            }
            else if (ContentLength == default(long))
            {
                _requestContentBuffer = new byte[int.MaxValue];
            }
            else if (_requestContentBuffer.Length != ContentLength)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref _requestContentBuffer, (int) ContentLength);
            }
            return new MemoryStream(_requestContentBuffer);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public static new WebRequest Create(string requestUri)
        {
            return new SocksHttpWebRequest(new Uri(requestUri));
        }

        public static new WebRequest Create(Uri requestUri)
        {
            return new SocksHttpWebRequest(requestUri);
        }

        private string BuildHttpRequestMessage()
        {
            if (RequestSubmitted)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted.");
            }

            var message = new StringBuilder();
            message.AppendFormat("{0} {1} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {2}\r\n", Method, RequestUri.PathAndQuery, RequestUri.Host);

            // add the headers
            foreach (var key in Headers.Keys)
            {
                message.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\r\n", key, Headers[key.ToString()]);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
            {
                message.AppendFormat("Content-Type: {0}\r\n", ContentType);
            }
            if (ContentLength > 0)
            {
                message.AppendFormat("Content-Length: {0}\r\n", ContentLength);
            }

            // add a blank line to indicate the end of the headers
            message.Append("\r\n");

            // add content
            if(_requestContentBuffer != null && _requestContentBuffer.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(_requestContentBuffer, false))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        message.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
            }

            return message.ToString();
        }

        private SocksHttpWebResponse InternalGetResponse()
        {
            var response = new StringBuilder();
            using (var _socksConnection =
                new ProxySocket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                var proxyUri = Proxy.GetProxy(RequestUri);
                var ipAddress = GetProxyIpAddress(proxyUri);
                _socksConnection.ProxyEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, proxyUri.Port);
                _socksConnection.ProxyType = ProxyTypes.Socks5;

                // open connection
                _socksConnection.Connect(RequestUri.Host, 80);
                // send an HTTP request
                _socksConnection.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RequestMessage));
                // read the HTTP reply
                var buffer = new byte[1024];

                var bytesReceived = _socksConnection.Receive(buffer);
                while (bytesReceived > 0)
                {
                    response.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesReceived));
                    bytesReceived = _socksConnection.Receive(buffer);
                }
            }
            return new SocksHttpWebResponse(response.ToString());
        }

        private static IPAddress GetProxyIpAddress(Uri proxyUri)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress;
            if (!IPAddress.TryParse(proxyUri.Host, out ipAddress))
            {
                try
                {
                    return Dns.GetHostEntry(proxyUri.Host).AddressList[0];
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        string.Format("Unable to resolve proxy hostname '{0}' to a valid IP address.", proxyUri.Host), e);
                }
            }
            return ipAddress;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public string RequestMessage
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_requestMessage))
                {
                    _requestMessage = BuildHttpRequestMessage();
                }
                return _requestMessage;
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Note that, as @casperOne pointed out, this makes use of a (free) third party library called [ProxySocket](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=9).

Comment: 17 people havnt tried out this code. If so, they would've noticed this answer is incomplete as there is missing code for the inteface and additional classes in here.

Comment: I've tried to google them, but even there you cant find it. Unfortunately useless this way.

Comment: @C4u It's not useless at all - if you read the code, you can see that IProxyDetails is a straightforward interface with a few properties on it whose types you can easily work out. What's missing is the implementation of SocksHttpWebRequest, which the OP took from the blog linked in the accepted answer. A quick edit will fix that.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for library in order to do this. finally i found the `MihaZupan/HttpToSocks5Proxy` it's a real lifesaver. just like this you can use it:

```
using MihaZupan;

var proxy = new HttpToSocks5Proxy("127.0.0.1", 1080,
   "username", "password" // optional
);
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = proxy };
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler, true);

var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(
    new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://httpbin.org/ip"));

Console.WriteLine("HTTPS GET: " + await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

If you want a more convenient, `WebClient`-esque API for reading the content, you can wrap the response-read calls into an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
  public static async Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(this HttpClient client, string url)
  {
    var response = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(
      HttpMethod.Get, url));

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For future readers:
Since .NET 6, socks proxies are [supported](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17740) natively with HttpClient.

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy("socks5://127.0.0.1", 9050)
};
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

#### Note:

In time of writing this answer, `WebClient` is considered as obsolete. `HttpClient` should be used instead.

Comment: You probably would get more upvotes if you copied the code from https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6099#issuecomment-858759926 to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I came across this aswell and found the nice [BetterHttpClient](https://github.com/Yozer/BetterHttpClient)

It derives from WebClient and allows you to specify a socks proxy:

```
BetterHttpClient.HttpClient client = new BetterHttpClient.HttpClient(new BetterHttpClient.Proxy("IP address", port, BetterHttpClient.ProxyTypeEnum.Socks));
```

Comment: This is so much better than the accepted answer and the higher upvoted derivative answer. This one works with a simple NuGet package AND works with HTTPS. No trying to figure out the missing parts of the code, or having it only work with HTTP.

Comment: BetterHttpClient is glitchy and deprecated. Don't use it

Answer (score 0):

Try [Yove.Proxy](https://github.com/TheSuunny/Yove.Proxy). Example:

```cs
using (var w = new WebClient())
{
    using (var proxy = new ProxyClient("67.201.33.10", 25283, ProxyType.Socks5))
    {
        w.Proxy = proxy;
        Console.WriteLine(w.DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org"));
    }
}
```