# Powershell: Get XML through a SOCKSv5 proxy

Tags: powershell, proxy, socks, dynatrace

For a reporting tool I need to download an XML which is only accessible through a SOCKS proxy. My idea was to install the proxy in IE but disable it, then in powershell enable it a few seconds so I download it, but that doesn't seem to work. Anybody got any other work-arounds?

Here is my code

```
$proxyAddr = (get-itemproperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings').ProxyServer
$proxy = new-object System.Net.WebProxy
$proxy.Address = $proxyAddr
$proxy.useDefaultCredentials = $true

$url = "https://appmon-apm.####.##/rest/management/dashboard/xmlgen"
$wc = new-object system.net.WebClient
$wc.proxy = $proxy
$webpage = $wc.DownloadData($url)
$str
```

Comment: `WebClient` doesn't support SOCKS, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965130/4137916). PowerShell can, of course, call any .NET code you like by importing it with `Add-Type`.