# How do I use Socks5 proxies with the WebClient class?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, httpwebrequest, webclient

So I've been playign around with some code, looking at MSDN and trying to figure out how to use Socks5 proxies with the `WebClient` class.
As from what I understand you can NOT use Socks5 proxies with the WebClient class, however the information I read was back from `C# 4.0` and I am not sure of things has changed up unil `C# 7.0`

What are my alternatives? How do I make use of Socks5 proxies when making a webrequest?

This keeps timing out, it's a socks4 proxy.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Proxy = new WebProxy("109.197.26.224:39880");

            var content = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://cmyip.org"));
```

Comment: The answer is no, and no again. Your research is correct and nothing has changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use WebClient with socks proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122369/use-webclient-with-socks-proxy)

Comment: Either use a specialized library, or see the duplicate page for an example of how to Frankenstein `WebRequest` and `WebClient` to add the functionality you need

Comment: hey, what is your reason for wanting to use Socks? Are you trying to be anonymous or is it a business requirement?